# Add serial port to VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, serial-port

I am using Fedora 12 and VirtualBox 3.1.2. My guest OS is Windows XP. How to add a serial port which will be 'physically' connected to /dev/ttyUSB0?

Answer (score 4):

This is all set out in the VirtualBox documentation. Particularly [online](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#serialports) or in the [pdf](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/3.1.2/UserManual.pdf). Essentially run VirtualBox and go,

```
(VM name) > Settings > Serial Ports > Enable port > connect to device
```

And add the name of your device. Be careful about file permissions.

If you're running headless, I think you can do it through `VBoxManage modifyvm`.